# Edit class and method so its callable from another method

Tags: java, class, methods, java-8, return-type

my Java is a bit rusty so I have a very basic issue.

I have a class `Dashboard` which eventually creates an `JFXPanel chartFxPanel` and I want `chartFxPanel` to display a specific scene using `chartFxPanel.setScene(scene)`.

I have another class `BarChart` which will eventually generate a barchart from SQL Data.

For learning reasons I got this BarChart source code from oracle tutorials which generates a scene, but, unfortunately also has a main method which is more then I need right now.

**updated code implementing Sabirs Answer**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartSample extends Application {
    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";
    final static String france = "France";
    final static String italy = "Italy";
    final static String usa = "USA";

@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final BarChart<String,Number> bc = 
    new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
    xAxis.setLabel("Country");       
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("2003");       
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 10000));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 35407.15));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 12000));      

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("2004");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 57401.85));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 41941.19));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 45263.37));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 117320.16));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 14845.27));  

    XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    series3.setName("2005");
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 45000.65));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 44835.76));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 18722.18));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 17557.31));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 92633.68));  

    Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
    bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    setScene(scene);
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
}

public void setScene(Scene scene) {
    this.scene = scene;
}

public static Scene getScene() {
    return scene;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

How I want to access the `scene` in my `Dashboard`-Class:

```
    private void initFX(JFXPanel chartFxPanel) {
    Scene scene = BarChartSample.getScene();
    chartFxPanel.setScene(scene);
}
```

So what I would need now is a way/explanation how to turn this class into a class which returns `scene` and which i can call from inside my `Dashboard` class.

Thanks for your help,

b

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood your question fully so below is answer that might solve your issue as per my understanding. Let me know if I misunderstood your question as I am not so sure what to ask to further explain your question.

You can create an class instance variable and use getter & setter methods in class - `BarChartSample`. You can leave `main()`method as is since that is harmless.

So,

```
public class BarChartSample extends Application {
 .....
 .....
 //Add this 
 private Scene scene;

@Override 
public void start(Stage stage) {
.....
.....

Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
stage.setScene(scene);
//Add this line 
setScene(scene);
stage.show();

}
//Add these two methods 

public void setScene(Scene scene){
 this.scene = scene;
}



 public Scene getScene(){
    return scene;
   }
  }
```

Now whichever class want to access this `scene` can access via `getScene()` method.

Comment: it seems that you helped, since the code that you write seems to adress the problem that I encountered.

anyway, when in implemented it i got an error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getScene() from the type BarCharts`

maybe i called the getter in a bad way?

`private static void initFX(JFXPanel chartFxPanel) {

  Scene scene = BarCharts.getScene();

  chartFxPanel.setScene(scene);

 }`

Comment: You can't call a non - static method directly from a static method i.e. without an instance object while non - static methods can call static methods directly.That is a Java rule.You might try , `new BarCharts.getScene();`

Comment: i turned `public Scene getScene()` into `public static Scene getScene()` , now i don't get any more compiling errors.

but i wonder if the scene is only available after `start()` has been called and this gets evoked by `main()`?

Comment: Also, just to be frank, these are very basics of Core Java & you should first try to have a Java course or study a comprehensive Java reference text first . `Scene` would be available but will be `null` , will have correct value only after setter has been called so try to get only after calling setter.

Comment: i know that these issues are very basic. actually those questions appear while i am implementing this for *learning reasons*  (as stated in the question ;) ) so if you could point out a hint how to call the setter before, i will again be  very thankful.

Comment: Update your question with your updated code. I am not sure what all you have changed. Looks like, you have a new class `BarCharts` now.

Comment: no, i just renamed it. will update the question now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145939/discussion-between-sabir-khan-and-bngschmnd).